# Was the Help and Improvement Queue Nuked?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, help-improvement

Going into the review screen today I noticed that the Help and Improvement queue was at 0.  If I remember correctly from last Friday there was over 600 questions in there.  Did the queue get forcefully cleared out or was there just a big run on people editing questions and getting them out of there?  Along with that is there any way to see the history of the actual queue and not just my own review history?

Comment: `Along with that is there any way to see the history of the actual queue and not just my own review history?` If you have 10k rep, yes.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the info.

Comment: There is a test running, which might repeat a few times in the coming months. This is a very valid question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, it's still there and still being used. However, we're (temporarily) sending fewer items into the queue in order to test its effectiveness.

**Preemptive background info:** not every question that needs help makes it into this queue, even under normal circumstances. The system attempts to identify questions that might actually *benefit* from a bit of careful attention and sends those through (sometimes repeatedly). For the next ~20 hours, it'll just be sending *roughly half as many* of them through the queue so that we may better determine if these reviews are actually accomplishing anything useful.

Comment: A randomized controlled trial for reviews?  Nice!

Comment: Note, this data also only gets better as it ages, because we can better study what _ultimately_ happened from both groups without having to run the test again. We're trying to _not_ run this often, but we're hardly responsible if we _don't_ test.

Comment: Could this explain items getting out of the queue? There were at some point 7 items in need of review. I reviewed two of then the queue was empty, 5 items needed review (I thought others were actively handling them), but those five never showed up in the daily review count.

Comment: Nice that you've at least recognized there's a problem and are attempting to do something against it - but why not simply *fix the damn triage queue* instead of filtering the crappy triage results with probably yet another machine learning approach?